# Monte Carlo simulation for economic growth

Tags: statistics, sampling, monte-carlo, discrete-time

internet. For the institution I work for, I need to investigate economic data. What I was asked for is that based on any historical economic data of the country, I need to build "base","pessimistic" and "optimistic" scenarios and assign them probabilities to occur based on data. For example, I used quarterly gdp growth values for 1999-2023 and then used the random picking method 10.000 times. I said if GDP growth is below 0.5 this is a "pessimistic" scenario and has % a 7.5 probability of occurring, if growth is between 0.5 and 4 this is the base scenario and has %85 probability. If it is greater than 4 it is an "optimistic" scenario. Basically, I need to divide the economy into 3 sections with probabilities. However, with assigned probabilities numbers will change, plausibly. These probabilities will pave the way for the forecast of the country.

My boss wants me to include other variables such as CDS, interest rates, industrial production, etc. But how can I build a multivariate simulation model and then say if CDS>x and Growth>y this is a pessimistic scenario and it has the probability of "Y" occurring?
Or do I need to use monte carlo simulation, can there be any other statistical methods?

Comment: This is very vague.  Modeling the economy of an entire nation is a complex business, with many, many factors...including (but far from limited to) the ones you mentioned.  I suggest sitting with your boss to learn (or possibly to map out) what sort of model is expected here.

Comment: I am not modeling it yet. What I need to basically divide the historical economic situation of the economy into 3 parts and then assign them probabilities. For example, I can claim, in the past if growth was between 1 and 4 %75 times. I can say our "base" scenario is this and it has %75 probability. But I need to include other variables as well. And I need to pick a threshold. So this is not modeling, yet. Just, dividing the economy into parts with the independent variables used. Any idea is welcomed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Monte Carlo/bootstrap, data fitting, QQ-plots, density estimation tests, kernel estimation, etc. There are a lot of methods but some will work better than others depending on what your data looks like. Do you have different data for the other variables that need to be included? I would suggest to work through them one by one.

Comment: I need to include GDP growth, CDS, inflation or any other variable. I can log differentiate them, multiply them, add them basically do whatever I want, then I should say "Yes, I split the economy into 3 scenarios with probabilities that occurred in the past". But the question is, for example, I can randomly pick 1000 times my variables. Then if I implement kernel estimation, what will be the threshold for my numbers? For example, how can I say "based on our multivariate kernel estimation if x<3 this is is the base scenario and it has % a 7.5 chance of occurring". I hope I made myself clear.